# Using Gradle plugin inside separated Task

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Previously I had a root `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "gradle.plugin.se.bjurr.gitchangelog:git-changelog-gradle-plugin:1.55"
    }
}
```

And module's `build.gradle` where I `apply plugin: "se.bjurr.gitchangelog.git-changelog-gradle-plugin"` and create a custom task inherited from a task from plugin

```
class ReleaseNotesTask extends GitChangelogTask {....}
```

In this case everything works fine, but now I want to extract `ReleaseNotesTask` to a separate file and put it to `buildScr` folder.

So I moved all code related to this plugin to build.gradle in the `buildSrc`

```
buildscript { 
    repositories { 
        maven { 
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" 
        } 
    } 
    dependencies { 
        classpath "gradle.plugin.se.bjurr.gitchangelog:git-changelog-gradle-plugin:1.55" 
    } 
}

apply plugin: "se.bjurr.gitchangelog.git-changelog-gradle-plugin"
```

Now my task, that's also moved to `buildSrc`, couldn't resolve references to classes in the plugin.
I tried to create Task in Groovy and in Kotlin, no success.
I see that using of `apply plugin:` inside root `build.gradle` is not fully correct, but I can't understand how to import classes from plugin to my task.